# How to disable/replace the image we see when an android app is running in background and we long press the "home" button

Tags: android

How to disable/replace the image we see when an android app is running in background and we long press the "home" button? Due to security issues, I need to disable this image.

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/crcco.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exclude it from recents from your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) or launch your activity with [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS).

To do it from the manifest, you need to explicitly add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to each `<activity>` tag.

Comment: Thanks.
But I don't have anything as "recent" in my manifest file!

Comment: You will have to explicitly exclude it, default is exclude=false, which means included. See above.

Comment: Can we add some different image in that place!